# Object Marshaling for C++/CLI Managed to Unmanaged Call

Tags: c++-cli

I'm writing a C++/CLI extension, and am having issues getting the typing to work out. I'd appreciate your help and hope that I'm making a simple mistake with casting or passing parameters.

Firstly, here is the definition of the unmanaged function I'm trying to call (and which I can't change):

```
int getResponse(const RequestObject& requestObj, ResponseObject& responseObj);
```

Second, my unmanaged C++ RequestObject has a definition like so (which I also can't change):

```
class RequestObject
{
public:
   RequestObject();
   void addElement(int value, int age);
}
```

Now, in my managed C++/CLI code (using the 'IJW' interop ability), I want to call into this function. You'll note that I have unmanagedClassInstance (which holds the method given by the above getResponse function definition), and ManagedRequestObject reqs (which is just the managed version of what I want to put into the RequestObject).

```
RequestObject* unRequest = new RequestObject();
// Here I'm taking things from a managed version of RequestObject and making
// the unmanaged instances:
for each (ManagedRequestObject^ req in reqs) {
    unRequest->addElement(marshal_as<int>(req->getValue()), 
                          marshal_as<int>(req->getAge()));
}
// Call into the unmanaged object to get the request processed:
ResponseObject* unResponse = new ResponseObject();
int result = unmanagedClassInstance->getResponse(unRequest, unResponse);
```

Can you please help me understand how to correctly pass unRequest and unResponse into the getResponse() function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you keep using pointers for your unmanaged objects (which you might want to reconsiderate), you should be able to call the unmanaged function like this:

```
int result = unmanagedClassInstance->getResponse(*unRequest, *unResponse);
```

But unless strictly necessary, I'd suggest you do this instead:

```
RequestObject unRequest;
// Here I'm taking things from a managed version of RequestObject and making
// the unmanaged instances:
for each (ManagedRequestObject^ req in reqs) {
    unRequest.addElement(marshal_as<int>(req->getValue()), 
                         marshal_as<int>(req->getAge()));
}
// Call into the unmanaged object to get the request processed:
ResponseObject unResponse;
int result = unmanagedClassInstance->getResponse(unRequest, unResponse);
```